# underhook of creating a library of c language

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

After c language is compiled, linked, the final production code has no method name left, as a result, this code can't be used as an api by the others, is this right?

After some search work, I found if you want to build a library, you just need to add -c switch to gcc, and then use the command ar. As a result, it means when compile using gcc with -c switch, the compiled code is keeping method names, then does it mean all api provided by windows is after compile but before linking? But, according to my understanding, the code can't run or be linked as a library before linking, so the guessing above is wrong. Then how to understand these questions?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating three kinds of compiler output: *static libraries*, *dynamic libraries* and *executables*.

*static libraries* consist basically of archives of `.o` object files, which can be added at link time to your program and are included ("statically linked") into the final program. This is the "library" you are referring to with `-c`. Typically, these have `.lib` (Windows) or `.a` (Linux) file extensions.

*dynamic libraries* consist of compiled code that has been linked together with a special option (e.g. `-shared` for GCC). Dynamic libraries retain *public* symbols, making them usable by other programs. If you compile your program against a dynamic library, the final program includes only *references* to the library - the actual code will be included at runtime dynamically. This is the meaning of the extension `.dll` on Windows - "Dynamic Link Library". Typically, these have `.dll` (Windows), `.so` (Linux) or `.dylib` (OS X) file extensions.

*executables* consist of compiled code that has been linked together in the usual way to make them directly runnable. Although some executables retain symbol information for debugging purposes, they are usually not dynamically loadable and their code can't usually be used by other programs (this is what you meant by "final production code" in your question).

Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: Great thanks. So "static libraries" compiled will have no public symbols, is this right? It's just commonly compiled, it's usage is to "statically linked" into the final program. Because it has already been linked to the target program, it's unnecessary to deliver a static library to the client who want to use the target program, is this right?

Comment: Yes - once a static library has been linked in, the executable contains its code. Distributing the static library is therefore unnecessary.